# Pycord bot not responding to commands

Tags: python, pycord

I have a discord bot with automod and XP system. I have made discord bots before so I know how to make a command, but now it does not seem to work and I don't know why.

When I say a curse it deletes my message and everything there works fine so the on_message works, but those commands don't work. It does not give any error when I type a command, but the but doesn't respond.
Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# Set up the client and command prefix
intents = discord.Intents.all()  # Enable all intents
client = commands.Bot(prefix='$', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    print("ping")
    await ctx.send('pong')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Ignore messages sent by the bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    # Do some XP things
    ...

    # AutoMod things
    ...

    # Process any commands that are sent by the user
    await client.process_commands(message)
    print("processing commands")



@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    # do something
    ...

# Start the bot
client.run('TOKEN')
```

Also all intents are enabled in discord developer portal

So what I expected to happen is the program would first print `Bot ready`. Then I would write `$ping` to discord and the program would print `processing commands` and then print `pong` and say `pong` in discord.

What actually happened is that the program Printed `Bot ready`. Then I wrote `$ping`, the program prints `processing commands`. And then nothing else happens

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It seems like this isn't an issue with the event on_message, as the bot already ran through it. This must be something with processing commands itself...

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `@client.command` with `@client.slash_command` and `ctx.send('pong')` with `ctx.respond('pong')` it works as a slash command. You can also remove `await client.process_commands(message)`. Discord no longer supports bots that don't use slash commands (see [this](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/6025578854295-Why-We-Moved-to-Slash-Commands) post by discord for more information). [Here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/application_commands.html) is the pycord documentation for slash commands.